# What would using staff in main hand while using a light shield and rod in offhand entail?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shield

Is it possible to use a Light Mithril shield +5 (I believe I can enhance shield?) in my offhand and a rod of (metamagic or absorption) in the same hand and still receive the AC bonus from the shield?

In my main hand I plan on having a staff or wand while rod and shield are in offhand. Would having these items in hand interrupt my casting of regular spells?

I'm playing an oracle/sorcerer, so components aren't an issue.

Then if the rod of absorption/metamagic is used to block a spell or enhance spell would this disregard my shield bonus until next turn, similar to using the shield to shield bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes. You can use a light shield with a Metamagic Rod

For any shield aside from a buckler, which is strapped to your arm, you must have a hand to hold it. However, You would be able to use that hand to hold an item, per the ruling for light steel shields and wood shields:

From http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/shield-light-wooden-or-steel

> *You strap a shield to your forearm and grip it with your hand. A light shield's weight lets you carry other items in that hand, although you cannot use weapons with it.*

As opposed to Heavy steel and wood shields:

From http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/shield-heavy-wooden-or-steel

> *You strap a shield to your forearm and grip it with your hand. A heavy shield is so heavy that you can't use your shield hand for anything else.*

So yes, it is possible to use a hand holding a light shield to also hold a metamagic rod, however you cannot use weapons with it.

### Yes, You can trigger a staff in one hand.

Also, about the question of whether or not a staff can be used in one hand, that can be found here:

From http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves

> Activation: Staves use the spell trigger activation method, so casting a spell from a staff is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity. If the spell being cast has a longer casting time than 1 standard action, however, it takes the full casting time to cast the spell from a staff. **To activate a staff, a character must hold it forth in at least one hand (or whatever passes for a hand, for nonhumanoid creatures).**

### Yes, Not having a free hand would prevent you from using spells with Somatic Components

And as to the question of whether or not having items in your hands would prohibit you from casting certain spells, the answer to that is yes as well, listed below:

From http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic

> Somatic (S)
>
> A somatic component is a measured and precise movement of the hand. **You must have at least one hand free to provide a somatic component.**

Meaning that if you don't have at least one free hand you wouldn't be able to cast spells that had a somatic component unless you were using the Metamagic Still spell.

Comment: +1, Note also that a sorcerer will suffer from arcane spell failure when casting spells with somatic components while holding a shield - even if he isn't holding a rod in that hand (unless the shield is indeed from mithral - than its arcane spell failure chances are zero)...